# Add an Exception to Cucumber Java Step Definition Template

Tags: java, cucumber, intellij-plugin

I´m using intellij with the cucumber plugin.
If I use the code template to create a Step Definition I get

```
@Given("User does sth")
public void userDoesSth(){
}
```

What I want to have is

```
@Given("User does sth")
public void userDoesSth(){
  throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
}
```

If I try to change the template in intelliJ

```
@${STEP_KEYWORD}(${STEP_REGEXP})
public void ${METHOD_NAME}${PARAMETERS} {
  ${BODY}
}
```

by adding a "throw new PendingException()" I get

```
@Given("User does sth")
public void userDoesSth(){
  throw new cucumber.api.PendingException();
    }
```

Is there any way to change this?

Thx, Nicca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ's gherkin plugin replace `PendingException` word with `cucumber.api.PendingException`.

Even if you use a full-qualified name like `throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();` plugin appends `cucumber.api`.

It may worth to report this issue to Gherkin Plugin developers.
You may check if there is a fix after any `gherkin` plugin updates.

In the meanwhile, if it is a necessary to have step generation from IDE, you may use **temporarily** this snippet.

```java
@${STEP_KEYWORD}(${STEP_REGEXP})
public void ${METHOD_NAME}${PARAMETERS} {
  throw new RuntimeException("TODO: implement me");
}
```

This will imitate PendingException's behaviour.